# VPN - multiple datacenters, multiple clients

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

We're a small company and we have two cloud providers, mostly because of price, and no on-premises infrastructure (but we're considering it). And I'm a newbie into networking.

We need most of our servers not to be publicly visible but accessible from our computers. They're used mostly to experiment with training machine learning models so that you can run multiple experiments without blocking your laptop.

So far, these servers at one provider are behind firewall and accessible through OpenVPN. However, the servers at the second provider are visible on the internet which I'd like to avoid.

I need to be able to connect to both clouds and the cloud servers should also see each other.

I can imagine how to configure a site-to-site OpenVPN connection between the datacenters and two connections from each of the clients to both datacenters.

The problem I can see is that if we'd add a datacenter, there would be many more tunnels needed. How can I avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new to this. Can you please explain what kind of details would help? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of creating a full mesh vpn (every site connects to every other site) you could deploy a hub-and-spoke vpn where you have tunnels from each site to your HQ (the hub) but no tunnels between the remote sites (spokes), so they route all their traffic to the hub. Downside is obviously that you consume more bandwidth  (and possibly need a bigger router and/or vpn concentrator) at the HQ, and latency maybe higher. Alternatively you could do something in between, i.e. a *partial mesh* so similar to hub&spoke but additional direct links between *some* spokes (e.g. the 2 clouds)